# When can a sum and integral be interchanged for distributions?

Tags: distribution-theory

There is quite a lot of information about exchanging a limit and integral for functions and the condition for that is known to be the dominated convergence. Is there anything similar which can be established for distributions? Meaning, is it possible to establish a rule for when
$$\int_{a}^{b}\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}f(x,\,\varepsilon)\,dD(x,\,\varepsilon)=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\int_{a}^{b}f(x,\,\varepsilon)\,dD(x,\,\varepsilon)$$
if $D(x,\,\varepsilon)$ denotes a distribution and $f(x,\,\varepsilon)$ is a test function?
I was able to find examples in which this rule works and in which it fails, but could not find a place which discuss that in the literature.

Comment: what do you even mean by integrating a distribution? Also, $D(x,\epsilon)$ makes no sense (even though people often abuse notation and write it as such); distributions can’t be evaluated pointwise.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about your comment. Can't I, for example, perform an integration over a test function with the Heaviside distribution as a measure when both are dependent on an additional parameter that I want to play with?

Comment: so, are you considering $D$ to be a measure rather than a general distribution? Note that not all distributions are measures. For a general distribution, you can only consider their pairing $\langle D_{\epsilon},f\rangle$, which need not have any integral representation.

Comment: Yes, as a measure it's good enough for my purpose. Thanks for mentioning the other point.